# Droid: Size buttons in horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a table layout that had 3 buttons scaled to fill the bottom of the screen. I want to replace these buttons with a scrollview to fit more buttons. I added a scrollview and added the buttons, but they have reduced in width to 1/4 of the width, four buttons wide. The scrollview works fine, but I can't scale it or the buttons, and on a larger display the buttons remain small where they used to scale.

Here's my row code:

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="6" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_low"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/sgbutton"
                    android:onClick="preLaunch"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:tag="1"
                    android:text="@string/button_label_low"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_high"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/sgbutton"
                    android:onClick="preLaunch"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:tag="2"
                    android:text="@string/button_label_high"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_practice"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/sgbutton"
                    android:onClick="preLaunch"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:tag="3"
                    android:text="practice"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button012"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/sgbutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:tag="1"
                android:text="@string/button_label_low"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button011"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/sgbutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:tag="2"
                android:text="@string/button_label_high"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button013"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/sgbutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:tag="3"
                android:text="practice"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </TableRow>
```

How do I get the buttons to scale to 1/3rd of the display width?

Comment: Try changing the `layout_width` of each button to `"0dp"`, so they will play better with the weights. Also, try changing your `weightSum` to 3, keeping each button's weight 1.

Comment: Nice idea, didn't work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to explain.

When measuring children views, LinearLayout will first try to divide its space to its children depending on how big the child view want to be, and then divide the rest of space depending on their weight.

Before dividing space, the parent LinearLayout should know its width. But in HorizontalScrollView, LinearLayout do not know how big it should be, it have to measure its children view at first to get the sum size. In this situation, the weight cannot work, since there is no remaining space. The width of the LinearLayout is equal to the width sum of the Buttons.

I think you have to set the width in your code. Set the width of each button to screenWidth / 3.

Comment: It seems to me Android's implementation of xml UIs is severely lacking. Why no percentage option for sizes? If I could set my buttons to 33% of screen width, and containing view to 100%, it'd be easy. Instead I have to do it in code, breaking the idea of standalone xml interfaces. If no other solutions come up, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can use weight for percentage, but it is relative to the parent view (the LinearLayout). And you can set the width of your parent view to 100% screen width using layout_width="match_parent", and it works when you only have 3 buttons. Now you want to have 6 buttons, which means you want the width of parent view to be 200% screen width, this is not supported.